# Android JNI doesn't find C++ standard library header files

Tags: android, c++, java-native-interface

I am following the [android-studio-jni guide](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-studio-jni/#0) and trying to compile C++ native code with gradle. Everything works great: I can load the JNI function, write C++ classes, compile, run and debug. And I don't need to write and maintain the **Application.mk** and **Android.mk** makefiles; both of them seems to be handled by gradle implicitly. There is only one thing that I don't understand: **How to include C++ header files from the standard libraries?**

I think I must have missed something in the gradle script, but I cannot find a good reference about what to add here. Here is the script:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "hello-android-jni"

    // I tried adding the following, but nothing happens
    stl = "stlport_static"
}
```

And screenshots showing that all the std headers are not visible.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are things needed to do in order make it work:

- Change the file extension from **.c** to **.cpp** so that ndk will compile the file with g++ instead of gcc.
- Add stl configuration such as `stl = "stlport_static"`, other options are `gnustl_static`, `system` and etc. I haven't tried them all but I guess it doesn't really matter if you are using some basic stuff such as `std::string`.
- Click of the sync button as indicated in the screenshot below. The getcha is that even if it says finish syncing, it will take some extra time to index the file and locate the header from stl. **So be patient, don't rush. Be patient, don't rush.** It take roughly about 10s for me. If you cannot find this sync on you menu bar, it is also available under **Tools > Android > Sync Poroject with Gradle Files**.

  [image]
- Lastly, update the code to C++ and test it out:

  ```
  #include <jni.h>
  #include <iostream>

  extern "C" {

  JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL
  Java_com_yuchen_helloandroidjni_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

      // TODO
      std::string message = "Hello World From Jni";

      return env->NewStringUTF(message.c_str());
  }
  }
  ```

Now it should works seamlessly. Go native, yeah!

---

Edit:

I don't know exactly what we need to put the code under `extern "C" { ... }`. But it seems it is important, otherwise, we will have error:

> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void com.yuchen.helloandroidjni.getMsgFromJni() (tried Java_com_yuchen_helloandroidjni_MainActivity_getMsgFromJni)

If someone any explain this.

Comment: Where is it documented that `extern C` is needed?

Comment: Hello @IgorGanapolsky, it cannot find a documentation about this. In theory, we shouldn't need to add this. Now that I am thinking about it, it might be a bug in gradle or Android Studio. But I have not yet found a way to work around this linking error other than adding this `extern C` tag. As the time I was trying, I am still using Android Studio 1.5, may be it has already been fixed since Android Studio 2.0 but I haven't tried it yet. Do you find it not necessary?

Comment: I am using AS 2.1.1, and I think it is unnecessary.  But then again, I am only generating **.so** files from the **.cpp** files...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky it may have already been fixed. We have been using the old makefile (Application.mk) system and the `extern C` is never needed with that. I may give this another try with AS2.

Answer (score 0):

```
"your-path-to-ndk-bundle"\platforms\android-21\arch-arm\usr\include
```

I don't see iostream there, so you can't import it. You can try to put extra libraries there and to the other processors include folder.